# How do I configure WebSphere Liberty with a JNDI DataSource for IBM DB2?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, websphere-liberty

I am trying to configure WebSphere Liberty 17.0.0.2 with a DataSource resource that can be injected using JNDI. No matter what I seem to do, I end up with the following error:

> com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionException: CWNEN0030E: The server was unable to obtain an object instance for the java:comp/env/jdbc/db2 reference.  The exception message was: CWNEN1006E: The server was unable to obtain an object for the jdbc/db2 binding with the javax.sql.DataSource type. The exception message was: java.sql.SQLNonTransientException: DSRA4000E: A valid JDBC driver implementation class was not found for the jdbcDriver dataSource[db2]/jdbcDriver[default-0] using the library jdbc-library. [d:\libraries\jtopen_9_3\lib\jt400.jar]

Java Code:

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/db2")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Configuration (server.xml):

```
<library id="jdbc-library">
    <fileset dir="d:/libraries/jtopen_9_3/lib" includes="jt400.jar" />
</library>
<dataSource id="db2" jndiName="jdbc/db2">
<jdbcDriver libraryRef="jdbc-library" />
    <properties.db2.jcc serverName="..." user="..." password="..." />
</dataSource>
```

I have no idea why it cannot find `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver`, or `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDataSource` since they are both readily available in the `jt400.jar` archive. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the IBM i Toolbox JDBC driver instead of the DB2 Universal JDBC driver, try changing `properties.db2.jcc` to `properties.db2.i.toolbox`.